# Apache Lucene - Where is SpellChecker class in version 4.6.0.?

Tags: java, apache, lucene, spell-checking

I'm using Apache Lucene 4.6.0. and I'm trying to implement a SpellChecker. However, I cannot find the SpellChecker class and the entire org.apache.lucene.search.spell package in version 4.6.0 of Lucene.

Can someone please guide me to this package, or the replacement package in version 4.6.0?

Comment: Well apparently it is there, a google for "apache lucene 4.6.0 spellchecker" resulted in the javadoc: http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_6_0/suggest/org/apache/lucene/search/spell/SpellChecker.html . EDIT: aha, it is not in lucene-core but in lucene-suggest (checked the source download)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this org.apache.lucene.search.spell.SpellChecker:

http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_6_0/suggest/org/apache/lucene/search/spell/SpellChecker.html

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
    <artifactId>lucene-suggest</artifactId>
    <version>4.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I have this dependency, but I get an error when I try to import org.apache.lucene.search.spell.SpellChecker - it says "cannot resolve symbol 'spell'"

Comment: The org.apache.lucene.search.spell package is in this jar:  http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/lucene/lucene-suggest/4.6.0/lucene-suggest-4.6.0.jar